# Javascript validation C#.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I am having a problem validating a textbox to not allow spacing. When the user enters a space I would like it to display an alert message and then clear the textbox, but the textbox doesn't clear. This is what I have so far.

```
function ValidateSpace () {
    var SerNum = document.getElementById("txtbox1")
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        alert("This field may contain no spaces.");
        document.getElementById ("txtbox1").value=""
       } 
   }
```

I have users trying to put multiple entries in this space but it should only accept one. The textbox is for inventory purposes so it would change the nature of the data if I were to remove spaces

Comment: Just as a note, don't clear the input as it's better for people to just remove the spaces from the input rather than re-type the entire thing again. If spaces are your issue why not just the .Replace(" ","") in C# to remove the space and replace it with nothing?

Comment: What's not working for you? You state that you have a problem, but not which one...

Comment: Also, please provide valid code snippets. At the moment you are missing a ) and a }

Comment: Chcek DOM to see if your textbox id has not been changed.

Comment: I don't get this. You write that you are not allowed to use spaces, but you can't remove them either..? Doesn't this contradict your constraint?

Comment: @Patrick. I have corrected the things you pointed out. I am typing on a mobile device and ot is a little rough. The users keep trying to use commas and spaces to differentiate between multiple entries. If I were to remove spaces upon submission it would change the entegrity of the intended data.

Comment: @Zaki textbox id remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have to bind keyDown event on textbox

try this jquery code to remove live the spaces

```
$("#IdOfTheTextBox").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});​​​​​
```

If you can't use jquery try with this javascript function (onkeypress event of textbox)

```
function NoSpace() { 
     if (event.keyCode == 32) { 
           event.returnValue = false; 
           return false; 
     } 
 }
```

if you want to remove spaces after the input you can do this

```
var noSpaces = document.getElementById("txtbox1").value.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Comment: I meant to post with my answers sooner, but I found what I was looking for with a small variation to similar code as your NoSpace function. Just added an  alert in with it. Thanks for your quick response.